# Cannot validate unless I add elementFormDefault="qualified" to XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I can't validate XML over schema provided by external WSDL service.
Validate throws this error:

**With validator online #1:**

> The element 'SolicitudEncuesta' in namespace
>   'ht*ps://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd' has invalid
>   child element 'CabeceraSolicitud' in namespace
>   'ht*ps://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd'. List of
>   possible elements expected: 'CabeceraSolicitud'. Line: 1 Column:204

**With validator online #2**

> Errors in the XML document:   1:  203 cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the
>   declaration of element 'SolicitudEncuesta'.
>
> Errors in file xml-schema:    2:  196 TargetNamespace.2: Expecting no
>   namespace, but the schema document has a target namespace of
>   'https://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd'.

If i add **elementFormDefault="qualified"** to schema, the XML **validation it's OK**.
But the schema can't be edited because it's provided for an external service.

**Schema:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="ht*p://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="ht*ps://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd" 
targetNamespace="ht*ps://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd">
        <xsd:element name="SolicitudEncuesta" type="SolicitudEncuesta"/>
        <xsd:complexType name="SolicitudEncuesta">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="CabeceraSolicitud" type="CabeceraSolicitud" nillable="true"/>
                <xsd:element name="Encuesta" type="xsd:base64Binary" nillable="true"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="CabeceraSolicitud">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="NumeroOrden" nillable="true">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:length value="11"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="CodigoControl" nillable="true">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:length value="5"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="CorreoElectronico" nillable="true">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="60"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
```

**And my XML:**

```
    <SolicitudEncuesta xmlns:xsd="ht*p://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="ht*ps://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd" 
targetNamespace="https://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd">
      <CabeceraSolicitud>
        <NumeroOrden>str12340000</NumeroOrden>
        <CodigoControl>str12</CodigoControl>
        <CorreoElectronico>str1234</CorreoElectronico>
     </CabeceraSolicitud>
      <Encuesta>1234</Encuesta>
    </SolicitudEncuesta>
```

**I think it's a Namespace problem**. I was reading similar problems in other posts, but I can't find a solution.

**UPDATE:**

Finally, using @kjhughes's knowledge i could validate over Schema correctly. And adding SOAP Envelope i was able to consume the webservice correctly.

**Final XML**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sol="https://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sol:SolicitudEncuesta>
         <CabeceraSolicitud>
            <NumeroOrden>XXXX</NumeroOrden>
            <CodigoControl>XXXXX</CodigoControl>
            <CorreoElectronico>test@gmail.com</CorreoElectronico>
         </CabeceraSolicitud>
         <Encuesta>XXXXX</Encuesta>
      </sol:SolicitudEncuesta>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

THANKS!!

Comment: The "htps" and "ht*p" are an intentional mistake.

Comment: What's the point of the intentional mistakes?

Comment: Don't declare `xmlns:xsd` or set `@targetNamespace` in your XML document; you're not using the `xsd` namespace prefix, and `@targetNamespace is an XSD construct that serves no purpose in an XML document.

Comment: @kjhughes stackoverflow can't allow me to add more than 2 links if my reputation is less than 10 points. If i modify the url format, the rule it's avoided. Sorry for this.

Comment: @kjhughes if i don't declare `xmlns:xsd` or set `@targetNamespace` in xml, i received the Validator Online nº1 error.

Comment: Links won't count if embedded within quoted code, regardless of rep.

Comment: No, declaring `xmlns:xsd` and setting `@targetNamespace` in your XML document simply would not prevent error #1.   See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37265321/290085) for how to update your XML to avoid all validation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your XSD has the "intentional" (?) mistakes corrected, and that it can be retrieved from `https://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd`, then the following corrected XML will be valid against it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<se:SolicitudEncuesta 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd 
                        https://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd"
    xmlns:se="https://arce.ine.es/ARCE/ficheros/SolicitudEncuesta.xsd" >
  <CabeceraSolicitud>
    <NumeroOrden>str12340000</NumeroOrden>
    <CodigoControl>str12</CodigoControl>
    <CorreoElectronico>str1234</CorreoElectronico>
  </CabeceraSolicitud>
  <Encuesta>1234</Encuesta>
</se:SolicitudEncuesta>
```